# I can't seem to get the current audio source url of the song played with just_audio from a playlist

Tags: android, flutter, dart, just-audio

My goal is to print on my screen the name of the current playing song of my playlist :

```
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
    // Start loading next item just before reaching it
    useLazyPreparation: true,
    // Customise the shuffle algorithm
    shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
    // Specify the playlist items
    children: [],
  );
```

For this, I created a model "Sound" that contains all the informations I need such as :

```
class Sound {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String url;
  final String category;

  Sound({
    this.id = '',
    required this.name,
    required this.url,
    required this.category,
  });

  static List<Sound> sounds = [
    Sound(
        id: '1',
        name: 'Brume Long Norm',
        url:
            'https://myurl.mp3',
        category: 'focus'), .... etc
```

Then, I filled the playlist's 'childrens' with a for loop in my **initState()** :

```
final tracks = Sound.sounds.toList();

tracks.forEach((element) => {
 playlist.add(
                AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(element.url)),
              )
```

So I would like to compare the audioUrl of the song that is currently playing, so I can try to match this url with one of my Sound object *(Example : get sound.name where sound.url == audioUrlthatIsPlaying)*

So for this, I guess I need to get the audioUrl of the current playing song.

I got this line in my **initState()**, I tried it everywhere else, it still logs me the same weird thing : ***I/flutter (28131): Instance of 'ProgressiveAudioSource'***

```
player.durationStream.listen((duration) {
        print(player.sequenceState?.currentSource );
    });
```

Any idea of how I can get the URL string? or maybe there's another easy way to get the correct song name displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store custom data in the `tag` attribute of each audio source:

```dart
for (var sound in Sound.sounds) {
  playlist.add(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(sound.url), tag: sound);
}
```

Then:

```dart
player.sequenceStateStream
    .map((state) => state?.currentSource)
    .whereNotNull()
    .distinct()
    .listen((source) {
  final sound = source.tag as Sound;
  print(sound.url);
});
```

Comment: Helpfull comment thank you so much! How can I use this variable "final sound" outside the map? I try to use is inside a Title component but I can't get the variable, even just out of the map

Comment: I'd suggest looking for a different question on that topic, as it's more related to the Dart programming language than it is specifically to just_audio.